# run setup in a subprocess created by xdist

Tags: python, pytest, xdist

I need to execute some setup (like creating a socket) inside each of the processes created by xdist before the processes start running the tests. I have looked at the [hooks](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-xdist/blob/master/xdist/newhooks.py) provided by xdist, but both `pytest_configure_node()` and `pytest_testnodeready()` seem to be executed by the main process instead of the subprocesses. Is there a way to do this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `pytest_configure(config)` hook is also executed on the slaves

just check of there is a `config.slaveinput`

i recall there are some examples in the builtin junitxml plugin

**edit:** link to code: https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/master/_pytest/junitxml.py#L225

Comment: Note that `slaveinput` was renamed to `workerinput` with the deprecation of the "slave" terminology: https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/commit/564b2f707dd558d10974268ab5a5494de2f90238#diff-40c29b1f1136f0a212e98384b44450adaf2c8808fdf14084d4ce78d63dc9d866R431